# openni grabber on linux

Tags: linux, cloud, kinect, point

I am using Point Cloud Library 1.7.2 on Linux.
PCL is working fine though the pcd_write example works.

But when trying to run openni_grabber it displays a window screen with three rectangles red, green and black.
I have checked that the Kinect XBox is working by running NiViewer and it works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: i will report this problem to pcl-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked pcl-users.org and the solution was to press letter R from the keyboard.